# Ajax WCF Restful Service Call Return Blank Page

Tags: ajax, wcf, rest, service

I am attempting to call a wcf rest service via ajax construct using jquery, however i am getting a bad request error when doing so from the jquery. Also, I try to browse directly to the service and receive a blank page.  I have done WCF service calls before in the past and cannot figure out what is wrong here. Thanks in advance to all that reply.  When browsing directly to the service I see no results.  Here is the jquery ajax code that makes the call:

$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://localhost:57452/mobile/WCFService/ContactService.svc/hello",
            success: function (result) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
            }

```
    });
```

Here is the service interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IContactService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "hello")]
        string SaySomething();

    }
```

Here is the service class:

```
 [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =      AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class ContactService : IContactService
    {
        public string SaySomething()
        {
            // Add your operation implementation here
            return "Hello!";
        }
    }
```

Here is the configuration for the service in the web.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SomeNameSpace.mobile.WCFService.ContactServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="LeeCounty_ASP.mobile.WCFService.ContactServiceBehavior"
        name="SomeNameSpace.mobile.WCFService.ContactService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="SomeNameSpace.mobile.WCFService.IContactService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.  It appears that when adding a wcf service, the default bindings added to the config file did not add the webHttpBinding.  Found the solution from this link, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132809/Calling-WCF-Services-using-jQuery

Comment: I have the webHttpBinding and I'm still getting a blank page. Did you do anything else to resolve this error? I have other REST services in the same solution that work fine